# Jquery Foreach inside Foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a foreach inside another foreach.
The first one is to foreach every WodTabIndex class found and the seconds one every input, link and select found.

here's my code

```
var StartId= 500; $('.WodTabIndex').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.children(':input:visible, input[type="checkbox"], a, select').each(function(i){
            (this).attr('tabindex', StartId + i);
                   (this).attr('tabindex', StartId + i);
        });
    });
```

I'm doing something wrong, but i don't know what. because never enters in the seconds foreach.

Sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lfvo/wk3w237y/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your code? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Liam like i sad, i'm trying to use a foreach inside another. But the seconds one never enters. Is something wrong on the seconds foreach? and this is my "story"

Comment: @liam... already debug it, if not i wasn't posting here...

Comment: What does *because never enters in the seconds foreach* mean?

Comment: Show us your html code. Make a fiddle with your html and jquery then we can help.

Comment: can you provide the code -in codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: What's `(this)` is that supposed to be `$(this)`?

Comment: the code should work fine as long as you replace `(this)` with `$(this)`: https://jsfiddle.net/7qp55dwh

Comment: What's the result of `alert($this.children().length)`.  Did you mean `$this.find(...` ?  You'll need to include the HTML or a fiddle if you want help with selectors.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary **to reproduce it** in the question itself.*  I'm sure you have, but if not, please read: [mcve]

Comment: @Luis using `.each()` inside a `.each()` callback isn't the problem (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/3c0z2ue0/). It could be that `$this.children(':input:visible, input[type="checkbox"], a, select')` doesn't match any elements and therefore there is nothing to do for `.each()`. How do you check that the inner `.each()` callback hasn't been called?

Comment: @SimonHänisch I Added an alert to confirm that was entered in the cycle. Because i know that exist inside the code at least one input or link or select.

Comment: @freedomn-m alert($this.children().length) this returns 2

Comment: I meant also with your selector, sorry for not being clear: `alert($this.children(':input:visible, input[type="checkbox"], a, select').length)`

Comment: Also, i execute this in the consol $('.WodTabIndex') and return the hmtl code and inside of one have one input. i'm trying to create a simple fiddle

Comment: ddi you try it replacing .children with .find ?

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, just replace to "$this.find(':input:visible, input[type="checkbox"], a, select').each(function(){" and returns Uncaught TypeError: this.attr is not a function

Comment: @freedomn-m Here's a fiddle i just created. May it helps https://jsfiddle.net/lfvo/wk3w237y/

Comment: Apart from some dumb typos in your fiddle, there's nothing wrong - so as long as your real html matches your fiddle html (which it sounds like it doesn't), there's no issue: https://jsfiddle.net/wk3w237y/2/

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m, it work with .find :)  Thanks a lot for you help, insteed some other users...

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with the code as posted:

First, you need to use `.find` rather than `.children`.  Children only look at the *direct descedants*, not at the entire DOM below the item.

So for this html:

```
<div id='top'>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
```

Code with `$("#top").children("li")` will not find the `li`s.

The second is that you need to use `$(this)` inside the loop otherwise you get `this.attr is not a function`

---

Updated code from the question:

```
var startId = 500; 
$('.WodTabIndex').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('input:visible, input[type="checkbox"], a, select').each(function(i){
        $(this).attr('tabindex', startId + i);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= $('.WodTabIndex').length; i++) {
 var $this = $($('.WodTabIndex')[i]).children(':input:visible, input[type="checkbox"], a, select');
 for (var ii = $($this).length - 1; ii >= 0; ii--) {
  $($($this)[ii]).attr("tabindex", ii+500);
        console.log("Row: "+i+" Checkbox index "+ii+" have attr tabindex: "+(ii+500));
        // inspect element to see result
        // each checkbox have tabindex 500, 501, 502, ...
  
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="WodTabIndex">
<input type="checkbox">
  
  
  
</div>
<div class="WodTabIndex">
<input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox">
  
  
</div>
<div class="WodTabIndex">
<input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```